# How to use _.each as method names for objects in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

I am new to the underscore library for Node.js and this question has been confusing me. I want to use the value in a key value pair as the first part of an object that I declared earlier, but I keep getting the error

```
TypeError: Object ax has no method 'push'.
```

The code that I've been testing on is below.

```
db_insert = {
  first:    'a',
  second:   'b'
}

ax = []
ay = []
bx = []
by = []

_.each db_insert, (val, key) ->
  db.view key, key, (err, body) ->
    unless err
      body.rows.forEach (doc) ->
        currentTime = newTime doc.id
        (val + 'x').push(doc.id)
        (val + 'y').push(doc.value)
```

I've tried with just having

```
a = []
b = []

_.each db_insert, (val, key) ->
  db.view key, key, (err, body) ->
    unless err
      body.rows.forEach (doc) ->
        currentTime = newTime doc.id
        val.push(doc.id)
```

but that doesn't work either. 
I'm new to Node.js, underscore so this might be a simple question of escaping, but I feel like when it calls on the (val + 'x') it creates a nested object that's not related to the previously defined array, thus as it hasn't been initialized as an array yet, the type is unknown. However, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val + 'x'` creates a string, so you cannot reference those arrays you previously created. I would recommend using a hashmap (JS object) for this.

```
var my_arrays = {
 'ax' : [],
 'ay' : []
 // etc.
}
```

Then, you can do

```
my_arrays[val + 'x'].push(doc.id)
```